# Unable to add more inputs to this form email attachment script

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment

I have been searching for a php script to help me send form results and attached images to an email. I found one that actually sent the attachments through, but I can't quite understand how to add more input values to it. It currently just sends the description in the body of the email and the attached images. I would also like to have other information show like phone number/location/website/etc. I have tried multiple approaches and searched here and other sites, but no luck. Can anyone please help me add to this code?

```
    <?
$strTo = $_POST["txtTo"];
$strSubject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);


//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["txtFormName"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"]);$i++)
{
    if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i] != "")
    {
        $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i];
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"][$i]))); 
        $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
        $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
        $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
    }
}


$flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
    echo "Mail send completed.";
}
else
{
    echo "Cannot send mail.";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show other information like location, phone, website etc., you need to add these fields respectively to the form that this script is sending from. For example, in order to get the location of the user, within the form tags, add a new input field like this

```
<input type="text" name="location"/>
```

Then, when the user enters their location into that box, like they would enter description for the email body, you add their location to the email body like so (I would start off with their basic information first):

```
$strMessage = "Location: ".$_POST["location"]."</br>"
```

"br" is just a line break.

Then you append the description to the email body like this:

```
$strMessage .= "</br>".nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"])
```

So let's say the user's location is New Jersey, and the description is "Hello, how are you?", the email body would look like:

```
Location: New Jersey

Hello, how are you?
```

Comment: Do these lines have to be placed somewhere in particular? I tried adding them under the top three lines but it has no effect.

Comment: You need to add the input text box on the form itself, and on the PHP script, add the scripting I showed you

Comment: I've added the html input name, and altered the php script but I still keep getting just the description and the attachments in the email.

Comment: `<?
 $strTo = $_POST["txtTo"];
 $strSubject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
 $strMessage = "Location: ".$_POST["location"]."</br>";
 $strMessage .= "</br>".nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);`

Comment: Is that how the php should look?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out the issue, it was unrelated to the code you gave me, and when I fixed that your code worked like a charm. Thanks for taking the time to help me out, I am very grateful.